# How to convert f units to seconds?

Tags: libgdx, duration

I'm using libGdx and in all tutorials I see #f (5f or 0.5f) as a duration or other parameter.
what does this f means and how I can convert it to seconds?

you can find tutorial like this [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-2-Actions.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f` stands for `Float` and is one of the Primitive Data Types of Java.
See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

`setDuration(float duration)` sets the duration in seconds.

So `setDuration(1F);` means it will last 1 second; 0.5F = half a second an so on.